# Private Class Variables vs Excessive Argument Passing

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, encapsulation

I am currently working on a single activity Android app that uses a lot of shared UI objects (like Button, etc). At the moment, I have these UI objects declared as private non-static class variables. The alternative to this would be to continually pass the objects from method to method and modify them that way. It is currently unclear to me which option should be preferred, as it seems to me that using the maximum encapsulation form would cause me to do quite a bit of argument passing. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Why would a `Button` be shared?

Comment: Multiple methods modify the text color on the button. It's shared only within the one Activity.

Comment: What is "a lot"? 5, 10, 50, 100?

Comment: @JohnRoberts: It sounds like you should have a method on the activity to modify the button colour. It's very hard to say with such an abstract example though - can you make it more concrete?

Comment: UI elements should obviously be declared as variables. In other situations I base my choice on whether it is possible to pass to a method 2 different values. I can pass different values to methods like print(String) or parse(String). But such methods as display(Button) will never change their parameters, so Button should be private variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally I like to think of encapsulation as hiding data within a single class. If multiple methods are accessing that object within the class, that doesn't really violate encapsulation principles. Once you start leaking it outside the class, that's when encapsulation problems occur.

With that said, it is perfectly fine to have a private member which is a Button and multiple methods can access that button.

Answer (score 0):

As above Jeff said You should go for passing arguments as you are inside one activity as you have mentioned in your question and encapsulation is always the first thing to be recommended.I will suggest to do one more thing if you can :

Define one function which will accept the color code or color type, and call this function from all the functions where you want to change the button text color.In this way code can be in one place which is performing the same operation i.e. changing the color.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if  those private non-static variables that you want to pass as arguments actually make sense to become the properties of the class.If you think it makes sense and have design control over their updation/modification you can go ahead and declare them as class members